# Relationship between FTP curve and FVA (Funding Value Adjustment)

Tags: xva, ftp, fva

By any way, does anyone know the relation of FTP curves constructed in bank to FVA (Funding Value Adjustments).
It'll be good if anyone could share some references here!

Thanks!

Comment: FTP stands for File Transfer Prorocol, Funds Transfer Pricing, Free to Play, Fourier Transform Profilometry, Finite Time Passivity, something else?

Comment: (been years since have been on here  @DimitriVulis - and a long time since been anywhere near needing an FVA price on an exposure, but since this just caught my eye as a blast from past, could plausibly mean sth like Funding Term Premium phaps, am sure OP can better oblige, Free to Play sounds good tho, rgds)

Comment: Betting on Funds Transfer Pricing myself. Please add some detail.